# How to do PS4 local coop in Terraria?

Tags: ps4, networking, terraria-console

Could anyone explain to me how to play local co-op on PS4 in Terraria? I've tried everything and it won't work. My account (US) and my son's account (BR) are logged into the same PS4. I bought the game on my account that has PS Plus and my son's doesn't have PS Plus. But I enter multiplayer, create the host and enter it with my character. Inside the game, I press the X button, but the screen does not go into splitscreen mode. Do both accounts need to have PS Plus?
What am I doing wrong?